# Construct count array in better than O(n^2) time complexity

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array `A[]` of size `n`, construct two arrays `C_min[]` and `C_max[]` such that
`C_min[i]` represents number of elements smaller than `A[i]` in `A[0 to i]` and
`C_max[i]` represents number of elements greater than `A[i]` in `A[i to n-1]`

For example `A[5] = {1,2,4,3,6}` then `C_min[]` and `C_max[]` would be
`C_min[5] = {0,1,2,2,4}`
`C_max[5] = {4,3,1,1,0}`

I am not able to think of an algorithm better than O(n^2) but [this post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/) motivates me to think of some better way of doing this, but am not able to able apply similar kind of logic(which is mentioned in the post) here.

In the given post, problem given is to find no of inversion in an array. if array[i] > array[j] and j>i then it forms a inversion. for example The sequence 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 has three inversions (2, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3).
idea used to solve this problem is a merge sort algorithm.

> In merge process, let i is used for indexing left sub-array(L[]) and j
>   for right sub-array(R[]). At any step in merge(), if L[i] is greater
>   than R[j], then there are (mid – i+1) inversions,where mid is the
>   middle index passed to the merge function of merge sort. because left
>   and right subarrays are sorted, so all the remaining elements in
>   left-subarray (L[i+1], L[i+2] … L[mid]) will be greater than R[j]

code for this logic is given below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int  _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right);
int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right);

/* This function sorts the input array and returns the
   number of inversions in the array */
int mergeSort(int arr[], int array_size)
{
    int *temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*array_size);
    return _mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, array_size - 1);
}

/* An auxiliary recursive function that sorts the input array and
  returns the number of inversions in the array. */
int _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right)
{
  int mid, inv_count = 0;
  if (right > left)
  {
    /* Divide the array into two parts and call _mergeSortAndCountInv()
       for each of the parts */
    mid = (right + left)/2;

    /* Inversion count will be sum of inversions in left-part, right-part
      and number of inversions in merging */
    inv_count  = _mergeSort(arr, temp, left, mid);
    inv_count += _mergeSort(arr, temp, mid+1, right);

    /*Merge the two parts*/
    inv_count += merge(arr, temp, left, mid+1, right);
  }
  return inv_count;
}

/* This funt merges two sorted arrays and returns inversion count in
   the arrays.*/
int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
  int i, j, k;
  int inv_count = 0;

  i = left; /* i is index for left subarray*/
  j = mid;  /* i is index for right subarray*/
  k = left; /* i is index for resultant merged subarray*/
  while ((i <= mid - 1) && (j <= right))
  {
    if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
    {
      temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    else
    {
      temp[k++] = arr[j++];

     /*this is tricky -- see above explanation/diagram for merge()*/
      inv_count = inv_count + (mid - i);
    }
  }

  /* Copy the remaining elements of left subarray
   (if there are any) to temp*/
  while (i <= mid - 1)
    temp[k++] = arr[i++];

  /* Copy the remaining elements of right subarray
   (if there are any) to temp*/
  while (j <= right)
    temp[k++] = arr[j++];

  /*Copy back the merged elements to original array*/
  for (i=left; i <= right; i++)
    arr[i] = temp[i];

  return inv_count;
}

/* Driver progra to test above functions */
int main(int argv, char** args)
{
  int arr[] = {1, 20, 6, 4, 5};
  printf(" Number of inversions are %d \n", mergeSort(arr, 5));
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

so can this count array problem be done on similar lines.

> Is it possible to construct count array in better than O(n^2)-time?

Comment: why downvotes without any reason?? I think some people feel brave in  downvoting a question rather suggesting solution or a reason for downvote :D

Comment: NMDV, Posting relevant information is an off-site link is frowned upon.  Better to post revilement data here - _and_ what you tried.

Comment: @AMomchilov what do you referring by saying previous values, previous means last array index which is accessed or last value which is just smaller than current element?

Comment: @chux What i tried is simple a brute-force approach which i don't think needs explanation.Its just two for loops which keeps track of cout. In the given link, problem is to find number of inversion count, and there a merge sort algorithm is used to find it in O(nlogn) time.

Comment: Sorting the array costs `O(n*ln(n))` so start with a sorted list.  Seems trivial then.  just walk the array

Comment: @chux: How does one associate the elements of the whole sorted array w/ the needed prefixes (or suffixes, for C_max)?

Comment: @chux could you please explain the procedure that you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you kept an array, S, where S[0..x] is a sorted version of A[0..x].  Then computing C_min[x+1] when you have already computed C_min[0..x] would amount to inserting A[x+1] into S (an O(log n) operation) and locating A[x+1] within S (at worst, another O(log n) operation).  That would make computing all of C_min O(n log n).  Computing C_max would be similar, but would need its own version of S, making computing both C_min and C_max O(n log n).

Comment: makes sense. Will try implementing it. :)

Comment: Which sorting algorithm will be suited for this increment approach, insertion sort can do it easily but how to do it in nlogn

Comment: @DeepankarSingh: You have to do *some* of the work yourself :)

Comment: in first impression, i dont think its feasible in O(nlogn) thats why i asked. here in your algorithm you're considering a new element every time and keep your array S sorted, if array is not static how come we keep S sorted in O(nlogn) time.

Comment: Even if we find correct position of A[x+1] in O(logn) time but in worst case we need to shift-right all the elements present in S.